# Android TextView Programmatically following XML

Tags: android-layout, textview, android-xml, android

I currently have this xml:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/dummy"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/test"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And im trying to convert it to a java version so that I can set a typeface:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// the get the activity_main layout (getContentView method does not exist?)
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);

final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setId(R.id.dummy);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams contentLayout = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
contentLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
textView.setText(R.string.test);

Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(tf);

layout.addView(textView, contentLayout);
```

The problem I'm having is that either does not gravity work or match_parent. The texts ends up in the upper right corner and not in the center as it does on the xml version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XML you're setting the gravity of the *text* inside the `TextView`. In the code you are setting the TextView's *layout* gravity.

To replicate what you've done in the XML, change the line:

```
contentLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

to:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

If your XML had `android:layout_gravity="center"` instead of `android:gravity="center"` then your code would match as it is.

Comment: Thank you! I never would have figured that one out. Does this mean that the TextView is actually filling up the whole screen? I thought that LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT would do that. I thought that the TextView was centered in the layout, but now i think that the TextView fills upp the whole parent and then centers the text inside of the TextView, am I correct?

Comment: Exactly right. I find it helps when starting off creating a layout to set background colour on all Views - to see exactly where everything is and how big they are. And by the way, FILL_PARENT and MATCH_PARENT are exactly the same.